# Is there a finitely presented group with infinite homology over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, geometric-group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a discrete group given by finitely many generators with finitely many relations. Can the homology groups $H_i(G, \mathbb{Q})$, or equivalently $H_i(BG, \mathbb{Q})$ (topological homology of the classifying space) be infinite-dimensional? Can they be nonzero for infinitely many $i$?

For any finitely presented groups I've seen, the answer is a surprising "no" (all finitely presented groups I know act on a finite-dimensional contractible space with finite stabilizers, and it follows that above the dimension of this space, homology vanishes). But it really should be the case that a "general" finitely-presented group has infinite homology... does anyone know of an example?

Comment: Just to make sure: the assertion that $H_i(G,\mathbb{Q})$ is finite-dimensional (for all $i>2$) is an assumption, yes?

Comment: Also, "infinite homology" means "infinite-dimensional homology" (as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space), right?

Comment: @Alex: I thought any group homology of a finitely presented group is finite-dimensional. Are there examples where $H_2$ isn't? And yes, "infinite" means infinite-dimensional

Comment: Yes, $H_2$ of an fp group is finitely generated. But, say, $H_3$ needs not be finitely generated. The first such example was given by John Stallings, in a seminal paper, titled, sure enough, _A finitely presented group whose 3-dimensional integral homology is not finitely generated_, see [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2373106).

Comment: @Dmitry: you should edit the second sentence of your question according to Alex' comments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thompson's group F is an example. It's finitely presented and, according to [this](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/papers/homology.pdf) paper of Ken Brown, the integral homology is free abelian of rank 2 in every positive dimension.

Answer (score 6):

This answers the other part of your question, not answered by Thompson's group.  For each $i\geq 3$ there is a finitely presented group $G_i$ with the property that $H_i(G_i\mathbb{Q})$ is infinite dimensional.  The first such examples were due to Stallings ($i=3$ and Bieri $i>3$).  Take a direct product of $i$ copies of the free group $F$ on two generators, and define $G_i$ to be the kernel of the homomorphism $F^i\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ that sends each of the $2i$ standard generators to $1\in \mathbb{Z}$.  These are the Bieri-Stallings groups.  For $i=2$ the analogous group is finitely generated but not finitely presented, and for $i=1$ it is free of infinite rank.  These groups can be viewed as special cases of the Bestvina-Brady construction.